# Viewing 3D XYZ vector file in QGIS with QGIS2threejs plugin

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis2threejs, three-js

Anyone know how to view points (vector file) in 3D using QGIS2threeJS plugin? It seems to work for terrain models but is not simple to figure out 3d point cloud plotting.

See attached fig. I am plotting terrain model with points which contain a depth dimension and I cannot get them to plot below the surface of the terrain model. Also adjusting the size of points by an attribute did not seem to work.

[image]

Here is an example of some of the points in 3D that I want to visualize in QGIS. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select for the correct field for the Z coordinate:
either Relative to DEM + "Field" or Absolute value "Field":
[image: qgis2threejs-table]
(my field is "Height").

Negative values work. Those spheres can be seen enabling transparency for the DEM:
[image: qgis2threejs-view]

Using a field for different sizes works for me:
[image: qgis2threejs - Size of sphere]
[image: qgis2threejs - Size of sphere]

Cheers,

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks, looks like my units were off not the plugin.